# Are emulation and hardware-assisted virtualization synonyms?

Tags: virtualization, difference, xen, emulation, hypervisor

What is the distinction between emulation and Full Virtualization, also called Hardware-assisted virtualizion (HVM)?

From this source, it is not clear what the relationship is.

> **Full Virtualization** or **Hardware-assisted virtualizion (HVM)** uses
> virtualization extensions from the host CPU to virtualize guests. HVM
> requires Intel VT or AMD-V hardware extensions. The Xen Project
> software uses Qemu to **emulate** PC hardware, including BIOS, IDE disk
> controller, VGA graphic adapter, USB controller, network adapter etc.
> Virtualization hardware extensions are used to boost performance of
> the **emulation**. Fully virtualized guests do not require any kernel
> support. This means that Windows operating systems can be used as a
> Xen Project HVM guest. Fully virtualized guests are usually slower
> than paravirtualized guests, because of the required emulation.

Source: [Xen Project Wiki](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Overview#HVM)

In the following book these terms are considered synonymous.

> At one extreme you have full virtualization, **or emulation**, in which
> the virtual machine is a software simulation of hardware, real or
> fictional — as long as there’s a driver, it doesn’t matter much.
> Products in this category include VMware and QEMU.

Source: [The book of Xen](https://books.google.cz/books?id=9284DkYwQCgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=book%20of%20xen&hl=cs&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=book%20of%20xen&f=false)

Following are the excerpts from an article describing the actual difference between emulation and HWM. However, the only distinction I can see is, that virtualization enables to create more than one computing environment.

> If emulation takes such a toll, why bother? Because we might want to
> do one of the following:
>
> ```
> Run an OS on a hardware platform for which it was not designed.
> Run an application on a device other than the one it was developed for (e.g., run a Windows program on a Mac).
> Read data that was written onto storage media by a device we no longer have or that no longer works.
> ```

Source: [Russell Kay](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2551154/virtualization/emulation-or-virtualization-.html#comments)

> Virtual machines offer the following advantages:
>
> ```
> They're compatible with all Intel x86 computers.
> They're isolated from one another, just as if they were physically separate.
> Each is a complete, encapsulated computing environment.
> They're essentially independent of the underlying hardware.
> They're created using existing hardware.
> ```

Source: [Russell Kay](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2551154/virtualization/emulation-or-virtualization-.html#comments)

There is [another article](https://powermore.dell.com/technology/emulation-virtualization-whats-difference/), which only supports my hypothesis.

> Emulation, in short, involves making one system imitate another. For
> example, if a piece of software runs on system A and not on system B,
> we make system B “emulate” the working of system A. The software then
> runs on an emulation of system A.
>
> In this same example, virtualization would involve taking system A and
> splitting it into two servers, B and C.

So lets consider B=C and we have emulation, dont we?

Comment: No. Emulation is to use software to "emulate" hardware. Hardware-assisted virtualization have the hardware to expose the real-hardware to software, instead of emulation. For example, you have one physical device, you can emulate it as multiple devices by using QEMU. Hardware-assistant virtualization will actually  add new registers to duplicate the hardware component and add the protection mechanisms for software to use this hardware device at different time. Different SWs will "directly" use the hardware at different time.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that virtualization is achieved by emulating the hardware components network adapters, USB, hard disk, CD drives etc in software. Thus emulation actually helps achieving virtualization.

Full virtualization is the technique of virtualization in which the guest OS runs unmodified, that is, the guest is not aware of whether it is running in a virtual machine environment or on a physical machine. Initially binary translation of the guest code was done in order to achieve full virtualization, but it wasn't good from performance perspective.

Para virtualization is a technique which requires modifications in the guest Operating System in order to gain better performance.

Hardware assisted virtualization is full virtualization technique as the guest Operating System runs unmodified. It is called hardware assisted because this type of virtualization utilizes virutalization specific extensions in host hardware like Intel-vtx, AMD-V etc. This technique not only offers full virtualization (guest OS does not require modification) but also has performance benefits and major vendors like Intel and AMD are providing extensions in hardware to support virtualization.